# JS file is not loading when i put wp_head() and wp_footer

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

In my WordPress project I need to use a WordPress plugin, For that plugin to work I have to put `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`. But when I put that than my slider's JS file don't load. `<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js"></script>`

Any idea how I can load my JS file with `wp_head()` and `wp_footer` Functions. The slider which I am using is bootstrap carousel slider (not plugin).

#### UPDATE

I have tried this in `functions.php` But still no success.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Here is my footer contents after my divs structure -:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/js/custom.js">    </script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/layout/scripts/jquery.fitvids.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js"></script>          
<?php wp_footer()?>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

I have put all these scripts in fuctions.php as follows

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name0', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name4', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/scripts/jquery.fitvids.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name6', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.2', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: You're doing it terribly wrong. Use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Can you put your code where you add `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` ?

Comment: @ Devendra Sharma I have put `wp_head()` just before `</head>` tag and `wp_footer()`. just before `</body>` tag. AND just before `wp_footer()` I am calling my JS files. If I put `wp_footer()` before js calling funtions then my slider starts woking but plugin stopped working. IF I put wp_footer() just before `</body>` tag then my slider stopped and plugin works.

Comment: instead of `array()` as the 4th parameter for enqueueing your jQuery scripts use `array('jquery')` to set jquery as their dependency, and set the handle (currently script-name6) to `jquery` (...and check if jquery is not already loaded anyway!)

Comment: @majick I didnt get the point `set the handle (currently script-name6) to jquery`. And all other point i try but no luck. I am getting this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status http://localhost:85/bow/js/custom.js?ver=1 `. And also dont know why in error its showing `?ver=1` Since I have already removed the version from the script but didnt updated that in question.

Comment: the last script you have enqueued in your code is jquery with a (duplicate) handle of `script-name6`... since the dependency is a handle it needs to match. and you should check that jquery is not already enqueued by your theme... maybe keep updating your code? as also you are using `get_stylesheet_uri` when it should be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` similar to `get_template_directory_uri`.

Comment: Can you **please stop the comment explosion**? You can discuss that amount in [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something more like this...

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // only enqueue jquery if it is not already enqueued!
    if (!wp_script_is('jquery','enqueued')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', array(), true );
    }

    // note: last parameter only needed here if custom.js actually needs jquery
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') ); 

    // all other scripts clearly need jquery to run...
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name4', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/scripts/jquery.fitvids.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name6', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.2', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

EDIT: to add this one separately in footer...

```
add_action('wp_footer','tabslet_script');
function tabslet_script() {
    echo '<script src="'.get_stylesheeet_directory_uri().'/layout/scripts/tabslet/jquery.tabslet.min.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand all your points. But still my slider is not working. Don't know why? When I put all JS link in footer and remove `wp_footer()` then my slider start working. But when I call via functions.php then slider don't work!

Comment: Hi majick! can I put `jquery.tabslet.min.js` code directly somewhere in my theme.

Comment: yes just add that one separately to footer if it is causing you troubles. see edit.